# Cooling fans not working after win8.1 install

Tags: windows-8, drivers, motherboard, bios, fan

I have Sony vaio vgn fw490 after updating from win 7 to win 8.1 the fans not working. I have installed speedfan but I can see 2 fans but I can't control them. In bios I don't have an advanced tab, so there is no fan control. It seems that all my drivers are up to date.  How can I fix this? [image]

Comment: Your laptop model [doesn't support Windows 8.x](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VGNFW490&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab) officially. You should list all drivers installed and their current version, because they might not be up-to-date. Being an unsupported operating system you would need to get the drivers directly from the device manufacturers, but those are usually generic and might not work with your laptop, if they're available at all. Either way, if the fans aren't working properly you should consider downgrading to avoid hardware damage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own - according to the first answer, the question is not related to OS upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened my laptop and clean the fan. It was little dusty. Now it works great!

Comment: Then it should have worked as well (or as bad) before the OS upgrade. Weather or not the drivers/programs showed that is another question.

Comment: Maybe it is just a coincidence